# Undocumented max length for urlfetch URL?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

I have an App Engine app that tries to fetch a long url. After experimenting it seems that for some reason App Engine limits the length of fetched urls to 2047. This is the stack trace for the error:

```
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 270, in fetch
    return rpc.get_result()
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 612, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 386, in _get_fetch_result
    'Invalid request URL: ' + url + error_detail)
InvalidURLError: Invalid request URL: <LONG URL>
```

The limit also applies in the development env. where I found the following code in the App Engine sdk  (`urlfetch_stub.py`):

```
_MAX_URL_LENGTH = 2048

if len(request.url()) >= _MAX_URL_LENGTH:
  logging.error('URL is too long: %s...' % request.url()[:50])
  raise apiproxy_errors.ApplicationError(
      urlfetch_service_pb.URLFetchServiceError.INVALID_URL)
```

Why does this limit exist? Is there a way to bypass it? It is really critical for me to fetch very long urls (I'm using a REST API service that require long urls).

Comment: Interesting comments in this post seem to suggets urls over 2000 characters are generally a bad idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Comment: Thanks @GwynHowell, I've seen this post before. It refers mostly to browser and search engines limitations. In my case it's a REST API call which I know doesn't have a url length limit, so I don't see any reason for App Engine to enforce a limit.

Answer (score 2):

This is an already reported issue which may be addressed in future. So I guess you have to just wait for now, or use some form of URL shortening (yuck).

You can see the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7053) and the related stack question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530180/why-is-there-a-server-side-limit-on-the-length-of-a-url).

In short, that limit was added to the stub to match the implementation on GAE so at least you found this issue quickly. I have no idea why it is limited.