# URL Size in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am calling a servlet in my app hosted on GAE. The issue I am having is that my request url is greater than **2048** characters and I am getting **400 Bad Request** error. While [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/#Java_Fetching_URLs_with_java_net) it is mentioned that we can make a request with **10MB** of data. So how can we send a request with 10MB of data? I am currently using free quota. A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530180/why-is-there-a-server-side-limit-on-the-length-of-a-url) was asked long ago but it is not answered yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppEngine limits aside, it doesn't make much sense to put 10MB of data in an URL.

When you take a look at the HTTP protocol, a `GET`-request looks like this

```
GET /path/to/resource?possibleParam=value HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

a `POST`-request like this

```
POST /path/to/resource?possibleParam=value HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Content-Type: */*; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 4242

here come the actual data with a length of 4242 bytes
```

So if you allow large amounts of data the in the URI of a `GET` request that would mean that the server doesn't know how much memory it has to allocate in order to receive the whole uri. So to get better performance it does come quite natural that one would restrict the length of `GET` requests and force you to use `POST` request instead where the `Content-Length` must be made known before actually sending bulks of information.

Let's take a look at the comments from other Stackoverflow users

[tx802](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1668204/tx802) said:

> POST your data?

[Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli), refering to the maximum allowed URL length, said:

> it will never be extended to 10 MB -- that obviously calls for a POST
>   or PUT (where data goes in the body, not the URL!)

That should make sense now, because protocol-wise it doesn't make much sense to push megabytes of data as a URI.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Sending megabytes of data in the request would rather warrant [POST or PUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) as the request method. This way you can send a request totaling up to 10 megabytes as you've noticed on the referenced article.

The reason you're getting the 400 error is [outlined](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.urlfetch_errors#google.appengine.api.urlfetch_errors.InvalidURLError) in the urlfetch errors module API documentation; the maximum URL length allowed is 2048 characters.

There is currently an existing [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7053) for increasing this length; although it's unlikely that this will change in the near future. You can 'star' the issue to get further updates and/or provide your use case in the comments.

Comment: Yeah, but it will never be extended to *10 MB* -- that obviously calls for a POST or PUT (where data goes in the _body_, not the _URL_!), as tx802's comment to the OP hints!

Comment: Updated the answer to suggest POST or PUT instead. Thanks @AlexMartelli.

Comment: You're welcome -- and BTW, http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html recommends a maximum URI length of *255* bytes (see under "3.2.1 General Syntax"), with a status of 414 as the response for too-long URIs... so a FR to extend the limit by *multiple orders of magnitude* above what the RFC recommends __might__ understandably be looked upon with a certain perplexity:-).