# Is there a url query length limit?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I have a GAE Standard node.js application deployed and use pagination in my requests to my default service via FeathersJS. I am seeing HTTP 500 errors if my url query parameters are too large. For example, filtering some data by 50 document ids in my Mongo database with a syntax like `asset_id[$in][45]=OBJECT_ID_HERE`. If I lower this amount to say 20-25 I will get the proper response back.

I have already made the appropriate changes locally to my project via the `qs` module and `query parser` property on Express to handle large arrays, and can confirm when run locally, on now.sh, and on Azure App Services these large queries work just fine, leading me to believe it's a GAE issue.

Is there a query url length limit in effect in GAE? Can we increase this value if need be?

To clarify this is server to server communication, not browser client to server communication.

Comment: Looks like my question may be a duplicate of [Why is there a server-side limit on the length of a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530180/why-is-there-a-server-side-limit-on-the-length-of-a-url)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maximum possible length of a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string)

Comment: [Extend the Maximum Length of a URL](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35892557) related issue on the Google issue tracker.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a known issue. [Why is there a server-side limit on the length of a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530180/why-is-there-a-server-side-limit-on-the-length-of-a-url) led me to [Extend The Maximum Length of a URL](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35892557) on the Google issue tracker.

Comment: The issue linked has been open for some time, but if you want to receive future updates you can 'star' it.  I've added a message asking for an update.